# Programmatically adding EditText box

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following text with me.

"**I drink tea and coffee**". Now the requirement is to change this text to "I drink `EditText` AND `EditText`"....Here the **EditText** is a edit box where in the user can enter answers once it is clicked. I need to make this change pro grammatically.

Any suggestions on this, as to how this can be achieved????

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code in button's click event handler:

`String str = "I drink tea and coffee";`
`String editTextString = editText.getText().ToString();`
`str.replace("coffee", editTextString);`
`str.replace("tea", editTextString);`

Answer (score 1):

You can ctreate activity structure in your layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

```
&lt;TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="I drink " />
```

```
&lt;Button
            android:id="@+id/firstAnswer" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="EditText" />
```

```
&lt;TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text=" and " />
```

```
&lt;Button
             android:id="@+id/secondAnswer" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="EditText" />
```

```
&lt;/LinearLayout&gt;
```

And set listners to your buttons

```
private String[] answers = { "tea", "coffee", "juice", "compote" };
    ...
    Button firstAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstAnswer);
    firstAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private int position = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((Button) view).setText(answers[position]);
            position++;
            if (position == answers.length)
                position = 0;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `getText()`

Example

```
Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

after that

```
 mEdit.setText("Tea");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this : `yourTextField.setText("..."+yourEditText.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

```
 EditText et=(EditText)findViewByID(R.id.yourId);
 Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourBtId);
 bt.setOnClickListener(
              new View.setOnClickListener()
              {
               public void onClick(View v)
               {
                  et.setText("You Drink EditText");
                }
               });
```

Put These code in onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewSwitcher`. This widget displays one of two views it contains:

```
    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ViewSwitcher>
```

And then, when button is pressed, switch it and load text from `EditText` to `TextView` or vice versa:

```
editText.setText(textView.getText());
viewswitcher.showNext();
```

or

```
textView.setText(editText.getText());
viewswitcher.showPrevious();
```

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4 textboxes with texts "I drink" ,"tea" , " and ", "coffee" respectively.
On the ontouch event of the 2nd and 4th textbox, you can display a textbox or edittext and edit the text. On a button click you can get the texts from the textboxes and display it again.